# Delphi FMX app: WebBrowser component remain blank

Tags: delphi

With Delphi Rio 10.3.3, i wrote a procedure that show a web page in a WebBrowser component.
Unfortunately the component shows a blank page even if it has the string of an html code as its parameter. And the stranger thing is that the page shows itself only after placing a ShowMessage after the loadformstrings method. I know that the WebBorwser is not painted by FMX, but there's not solution ?

```
sStr := 
  <html>
  <body>
     This is a Test !!!
  </body>
  </html>

WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank');
WebBrowser1.LoadFromStrings(sStr, '');

// ShowMessage('Test'); // If not commented out, the webbrowser shows the content
```

Comment: The main UI loop needs to run. Under Windows an `Application.ProcessMessages();` will do it. Better to do the work in a thread and leave the UI responsive without resorting to calls to ProcessMessages however.

Comment: Thanks ! I've solved !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct like this:
WebBrowser1.LoadFromStrings(sStr, 'about:blank');